# unmounting and powering off an external drive via command line

Tags: 16.04, flash

On the basis of answers to this question

[what is the command line equivalent of safely remove drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532586/what-is-the-command-line-equivalent-of-safely-remove-drive)

I wrote this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script works on sdb and sdb1"
echo "Have a look at the following and if all is well continue."

lsblk
read -p "press the Enter key if you want to continue..." key
udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sdb1
sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdb
```

I think the instruction "have a look at the following and if all is well continue" means that if the output from `lsblk` shows that the drive that we want to remove is the logical drive `sdb1` then continue.

The output from `lsblk` is

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   549M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 115.9G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   833M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 107.9G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  14.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.5G  0 part /media/jack/Flash
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0  89.5M  1 loop /snap/core/6130
loop1    7:1    0  89.5M  1 loop /snap/core/6034
loop2    7:2    0  88.2M  1 loop /snap/core/5897
```

The drive to be removed is indeed the logical drive `sdb1`.

This script worked well with Ubuntu 16.04 for the past 2.5 years. I use this script on average about twice a week. Then in December 2018 invoking the script caused my external mouse (Logitech Trackman) to stop working (on 2 occasions) or for Ubuntu to completely hang with a garbled screen (on 1 occasion).

Given that Ubuntu changes via `apt` it would seem that either Ubuntu has a new bug or that the script is obsolete. What is the correct solution or the correct script given the state of Ubuntu now.

Comment: You may want to run the script with `set -x` after `#!/bin/bash` or `strace -f  scriptname.sh`  to see diagnostic output and pinpoint at which command issues occur.  The script shouldn't be obsolete as `udisksctl` is still used and `fsck` too.  If external drive and mouse share same USB hub ( it's quite possible the two ports are in fact on the same hub internally ) it could make sense that both were powered off, though this would need some tracing to be confirmed.  Ubuntu changes to `apt` seem irrelevant also in this case

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I found that using the GUI also hangs Ubuntu. The GUI feature is the Flash drive icon context menu item "safely remove". The Flash drive icon appears on the Launcher if you have an external USB Flash drive plugged in. This problem is now a new askubuntu question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104176/safely-remove-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-flash-drive-icon-context-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem. Some kernels hang the OS. Details are at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099414/safely-removing-usb-3-0-drive-freezes-the-system-why-and-how-to-fix).

Since it is a kernel problem you can cause it to happen regardless of whether you use the GUI or the command line to "safely remove".

To quote from the linked page:

> This is known problem with latest 4.4.0-139-generic, 4.4.0-140-generic
>   and 4.4.0-141-generic Linux kernels. On launchpad it is known as bug
>   1803929 (currently confirmed by 5 users).
>
> The temporary solution is to use 138 ( 4.4.0-138-generic ) kernel.