I'm having trouble formatting a drive and need some help
Just to clarify from previous comments, I can confirm that the drive had finished creating the file system before unplugging it... See below for more details...
I'm using Ubuntu-Mate 24.10, and am having a very very weird problem. Of course, it's very possible that I simply just don't know entirely what I'm doing.
I'm trying to format an external USB Western Digital My Passport 2TB drive.
I followed the guide at
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z6ouBYfZr8
which is produced by a reliable source, (Learn Linux TV.)
I'm trying to do this with fdisk in the command line, as I am totally blind and just find doing it on the CLI to be easier.
So, I checked for the list of blocks on my system:
lsblk
and determined that sdb was my external disk, and specifically it had only 1 partition, sdb1.
I began by unmounting the drive
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
I then ran the lsblk command again, and found that there was no longer a directory mountpoint.
I then did
mount | grep 'sdb'
I got no output, which tells me it indeed isn't mnounted anymore.
I then went into fdisk
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
Once in here, I hit p to show the partition table and found that I had 1 partition, which is the one I want to wipe and also then reformat.
I typed g to create a gpt partition table.
I then checked again the table structure by typing p, and hitting enter.
Obviously, it shows no partitions due to me creating the gpt table. It asked me in doing so if I wanted to delete the current exfat signature already on the drive upon write. I told it yes.
So next, I pressed n, then hit enter to create a new partition.
I told it to make it partition 1, and I left the sector size alone, just hitting enter and accepting the default, as I wanted it to expand across the entire disk.
Finally, I wrote changes by hitting w, and then pressing enter.
Now back at my prompt, I typed
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
This wrote the file system.
Then, I did what was suggested in the above video... I unplugged the hard drive from my USB port, and then plugged it back in.
The problem is, after doing this, the drive isn't remounting.
So, I tried mounting it myself with
mkdir ~/disk
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 ~/disk
I know normally it should automatically mount upon insertion to the /media directory, but that's not happening. That's why I manually created a mountpoint, and tried mounting it there. - That was my logic of thinking.
However, this didn't work and it basically told me sdb1 couldn't be found.
Can someone show me where I went wrong?

Just as an aside (and I can't answer your question with any authority), but I wonder if the writing of data to your drive actually completed BEFORE you ejected it... ie. I'd have run sync to ensure data was written & ensured drive was powered off (I use GUI tools for this usually; but https://askubuntu.com/questions/532586/what-is-the-command-line-equivalent-of-safely-remove-drive may help if you're after a terminal equivalent command).  My 2c on what may have gone wrong, but I could be wrong here sorry as I don't know....

I think I'm just gonna stop using Ask Ubuntu altogether. Ever since joining, I've gotten nothing but answers like this with no help. I've asked questions, and I have clearly stated I asked a question, and I want help via the format of someone giving an answer. Clearly, that isn't happening. Instead, my messages are getting either closed or totally deleted up here. I get that there are places better to post some things, but I'm clearly following the guidelines on posting to this site. I no-longer feel welcome here therefore. I'm sorry to bother people, but I won't ever post here again.

Oh, OK. I apologize for my brash response then! I clearly did not see your first response in its completion. That's part of the problem that sometimes can occur when using assistive technology like a screen reader as I'm doing. So, forgive me for my response. I understand better now what you were saying. Might I suggest going forward, if you need to send a side-note like this to someone, please do so privately rather than commenting on their origional thread? It will help the community, and plus, it'll be more accessible in the long run for folks like myself. No hard feelings meant.

You said you used 'fdisk' I think you meant 'gdisk' Having changed the disk from MBR to GPT (I assume it was MBR) you might have to reboot your active OS for it to be visible.
